# Qualifying for other races' feats

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, feat-qualifications

Is it possible in general to qualify for feats that have another race as a prerequisite?  (I am thinking of something similar to how taking a multiclass feat allows you to qualify for feats from another *class*.)

In particular, my Sage of Ages (with [Sorcerous Vision](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1188)) would very much like to take the [Mythic Senses](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2679) feat.  However, this has Minotaur as a prerequisite.  Is there some way a half-elf bard can qualify for this feat?

I'm sure I've seen other feats change one's origin to e.g. fey or elemental - and that opens up other feats - so I hope something might apply here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A currently used character cannot...**

*Almost* Every way to qualify for racial feats generally revolves around character creation. The two main methods are to be either revanant-x (pick said race as your past life race) or a character theme that adds an origin or race keyword to your character. As Wax Eagle points out though, the *Reincarnate Champion* Epic Destiny can let you add another race's keyword for the purposes of qualifying for feats, but you must be part of a primal class to qualify for *Reincarnate Champion*.

In general certain races are balanced against one another by their racial features and related racial feats. 4e tries to keep these things separate so as to maintain balance.

Comment: Thanks.  I feared as much, though was holding out hope that some little-known feat or power would prove a loophole.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle You've already got access to elf and human feats, pretty powerful combination. There are other applicable feats to boost your init up.

Comment: You're right, it is powerful overall.  And I will have to go with other initiative-boosting feats, but they don't hold a candle to Mythic Senses, which would have been "your bonus to initiative checks becomes +43(ish)"...